# How to print first five elements of an matrix in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

My goal is to implement the following method in parallel:
public static double[][] parallelAddMatrix(double[][] a, double[][] b), then test my program on randomly generated two lists of size 2000 x 2000. Finally I have to output the first 5 elements of matrix a and matrix b, and also the first five elements of the result matrix, which is what I'm having trouble with.

This is the part of my code where I create the first and second matrix.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int var1, var2;
    final int matrices = 2000;

    // creates first matrix
    double[][] matrixA = new double[matrices][matrices];
    for(var1 = 0; var1 < matrixA.length; var1++)
        for (var2 = 0; var2 < matrixA[var1].length; var2++)
            matrixA[var1][var2] = 1;

    // creates second matrix
    double[][] matrixB = new double[matrices][matrices];
    for (var1 = 0; var1 < matrixB.length; var1++)
        for (var2 = 0; var2 < matrixB[var1].length; var2++)
            matrixB[var1][var2] = 1;
```

And then later created a function to create the result matrix...

```
public static double[][] parallelAddMatrix( double [][] a, double[][] b) {
    //creates output matrix
    double[][] resultMatrix = new double[a.length][a[0].length];
    RecursiveAction task = new multiProcess(a, b, resultMatrix);
    ForkJoinPool joinPool = new ForkJoinPool();
    joinPool.invoke(task);
    return resultMatrix;
}
```

How can I print out the first five elements for each of the three matrices?

I've tried stuff for the first and second matrix such as initializing var3, then under the "matrixA(orB)[var1][var2] = 1;", I put

```
for (var3 = 0; var3 < 5; var3++) {
System.out.println(var3);
}
```

and also tried

```
for (var3 = 0; var3 < 5; var3++) {
   System.out.print(matrixA[var1][var2] + "");
}
System.out.println();
```

Please help on this, and please tell where it would be placed for each one (I might have trouble with brackets).

Comment: You want to print the first 5 elements row-wise or column-wise? Depending on that, simply use a for loop, and iterate with one index constant and another varying from 0 to 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a nested for loop to iterate through the matrix, and a counter to see how many entries you've printed. Let's start with the easiest part: iterating over the matrix. I'll assume that the matrix is simply called `matrix`.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
```

You probably already figured that out. Now we need a counter to count how many times we've printed out an entry from the matrix.

```java
int num_printed = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
        num_printed ++;
    }
}
```

Ok. So now we need to stop once we've reached the end. We can't just use one `break` statement, because, we have two for loops.

```java
int num_printed = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) { // iterate over the rows
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) { // iterate over the columns
        if (num_printed == 5) { // if we've already printed five items, stop
            break;
        } else { // otherwise, print the next item
            System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
            num_printed ++; // increment the counter
        }
    }

    if (num_printed == 5) { // so that we don't go to the next row
        break;
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that you could create your own separate method, and only use a return statement:

```java
public void print_five_elements() {
    int num_printed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) { // iterate over the rows
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) { // iterate over the columns
            if (num_printed == 5) { // if we've already printed five items, stop
                return;
            } else { // otherwise, print the next item
                System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
                num_printed ++; // increment the counter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### More Specialized Approach

This approach allows you to use matrices that have less than five columns. However, since your matrix is 2000x2000, you could go for a much simpler approach. Use zero as the first index, and then just iterate up to five. Just keep in mind that this won't work if you have less than five columns:

```java
public void print_five_elements_for_wide_matrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(matrix[0][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there a need for nested loops? Since it is already mentioned that matrices are 2000*2000. Simply having a single loop with one constant index and another one varying from 0 to 4 (included), can achieve the required results.

Comment: @vatsalgosar You're right. I made my answer more configurable in case the matrix at some points ends up having less than five rows. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the matrices are of size `2000 x 2000`, you do not need nested loops to display first `5` elements from each of them.

```
int i;

//Display first 5 elements of matrixA
for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
    System.out.print(matrixA[0][i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();

//Display first 5 elements of matrixB
for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
    System.out.print(matrixB[0][i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();

double[][] result = parallelAddMatrix(matrixA, matrixB);
//Display first 5 elements of result
for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
    System.out.print(result[0][i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Note that the above loops print the first 5 elements of the first row (i.e. row at index, `0`) of each matrix. However, if you want to print the first element of the first 5 rows, just swap the indices e.g.

```
System.out.println(matrixA[i][0] + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Think of the first set of brackets as the row and the second set as the column.

```
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
     System.out.print(matrixA[row][col] + " ");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Since "multi-dimensional" arrays are really arrays of arrays you can do it like this if you wanted to print out the whole matrix

```
for (double[] row : matrixA) {
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Because of this, each row can be a different length.  So you may have to get the length to print them out like you first wanted to.

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrixA.length; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < matrixA[row].length; col++) {
       System.out.print(matrixA[row][col] + " " );
   }
}
```

Rows of different length of a "2D" array are known as `ragged-arrays`.